containerFactory in KafkaListener not working after upgrade to Spring Boot 3.4 from 2.5
Upgrading from SpringBoot 2.5.12 to 3.4.0 had the effect that KafkaListener could not select the bean specified by containerFactory and the following error is thrown.
11:27:40.337 INFO  [roducer-network-thread | consumer-test-1] [            org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient, 1017] - [Producer clientId=consumer-test-1] Node -1 disconnected.
11:27:40.338 WARN  [roducer-network-thread | consumer-test-1] [            org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient,  849] - [Producer clientId=consumer-test-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
11:27:40.338 WARN  [roducer-network-thread | consumer-test-1] [      o.a.k.c.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater, 1173] - [Producer clientId=consumer-test-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
11:27:40.720 INFO  [                             Test worker] [           org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics,  684] - Metrics scheduler closed
11:27:40.722 INFO  [                             Test worker] [           org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics,  688] - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
11:27:40.722 INFO  [                             Test worker] [           org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics,  688] - Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter
11:27:40.723 INFO  [                             Test worker] [           org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics,  694] - Metrics reporters closed
11:27:40.724 INFO  [                             Test worker] [              o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser,   88] - App info kafka.consumer for consumer-test-1 unregistered
11:27:40.734 WARN  [                             Test worker] [          o.s.c.support.AbstractApplicationContext,  635] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@213229a5 testClass = de.ingest.util.kafka.KafkaErrorRetryTest, locations = [], classes = [de.ingest.util.kafka.KafkaErrorRetryReceiver, de.ingest.config.KafkaTestsConfig, de.ingest.rx.ReactorSchedulerNewThreadConfig], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnectionContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizerFactory$OnFailureConditionReportContextCustomizer@41e9f86, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@2416c658, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1e6060f1, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@478fb7dc, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2a8dd942, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@372f0a99, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@640d604, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f4fcfb5d], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:160)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:326)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:510)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.<init>(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerDelegateCreator.create(ConsumerDelegateCreator.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:600)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:595)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer.<init>(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:453)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:430)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:875)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:386)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:520)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:264)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:520)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:436)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:323)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Below is the the class that contains the listener.
@Service
public class KafkaErrorRetryReceiver {

    public static final String LISTENER_ID ="test";
    public static final String TEST_TOPIC ="orders";
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private CountDownLatch receivedLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    private CountDownLatch succeededLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    private CountDownLatch errorLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); // throw error only once - recover on 2nd attempt
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GenericRecord> successfulRecords = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    @Autowired
    private ProjectReactorConsumerUtil projectReactorConsumerUtil;

    @KafkaListener(id = LISTENER_ID, topics = TEST_TOPIC, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void topicListener(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {
        projectReactorConsumerUtil.acknowledgeCompletableWhenDone(LOGGER, ack, consumerRecord, this::receive);
    }

    public Mono<Void> receive(GenericRecord record) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", record.toString());
        receivedLatch.countDown();
        if (record.toString().contains("fail") && errorLatch.getCount() > 0) {
            errorLatch.countDown();
            return Mono.error(() -> {
                RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException("simulated consumer failure");
                e.setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0]);
                return e;
            });
        }
        successfulRecords.add(record);
        succeededLatch.countDown();
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getReceivedLatch() {
        return receivedLatch;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getSucceededLatch() {
        return succeededLatch;
    }

    public CountDownLatch getErrorLatch() {
        return errorLatch;
    }

    public List<GenericRecord> getSuccessfulRecords() {
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(successfulRecords);
    }


}

Below is kafkaListenerContainerFactory
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    public static final String RETRYING_CONTAINER_FACTORY = "retryingKafkaListenerContainerFactory";
    private static final int BACKOFF_MAX_INTERVAL_MS = 7500; // must be lees than session timeout

    /**
     * Creates a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean.
     * @param configurer the configurer
     * @param kafkaConsumerFactory the kafka consumer factory
      * @return the concurrent kafka listener container factory
     * */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                                 ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
                                                                                                 ServiceProperties serviceProperties) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}

Below is the test:
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {KafkaErrorRetryReceiver.class, KafkaTestsConfig.class, ReactorSchedulerNewThreadConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class KafkaErrorRetryTest {

    public static final String REC_KEY = "msg_key";

    public static final String TOPIC_NAME = KafkaErrorRetryReceiver.TEST_TOPIC;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> producer;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaErrorRetryReceiver receiver;

    public void tearDown() {
        KafkaTestsConfig.deleteTopic(TOPIC_NAME);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReceive() throws Exception {
        var createTime = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
        producer.send(TOPIC_NAME, 0, createTime.incrementAndGet(), REC_KEY, KafkaTestDataUtil.testMessageWithValue("ok1")).get();
        producer.send(TOPIC_NAME, 1, createTime.incrementAndGet(), REC_KEY, KafkaTestDataUtil.testMessageWithValue("fail")).get();
        producer.send(TOPIC_NAME, 2, createTime.incrementAndGet(), REC_KEY, KafkaTestDataUtil.testMessageWithValue("ok2")).get();


        receiver.getReceivedLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        receiver.getSucceededLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        assertEquals(0, receiver.getReceivedLatch().getCount());
        assertEquals(0, receiver.getErrorLatch().getCount());
        assertEquals(3, receiver.getSuccessfulRecords().size());
    }
}

Below is the application-test.properties used:
# Kafka config
service.kafka.topiccreator-autostart=true
service.kafka.partitions=3
service.kafka.replication-factor=1
spring.kafka.admin.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT

#logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients=TRACE
#logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=TRACE

# kafka streams TopicAutoCreator - uncomment it when deciding upon increasing the replication factor for kafka streams
spring.kafka.streams.replication-factor=1
spring.kafka.streams.state-store-cache-max-size=0KB
spring.kafka.streams.cleanup.on-startup=true

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

Removing the containerFactory parameter from KafkaListener annotation everything works as expected.
